# Mock API call in model signal Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I am new to Django and unit tests, so any feedback is very helpful.

I built a small integration with a third party to create a matching account in their system whenever an account is created in our system. I do this on a signal in the model class. The signal is simple and looks like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Company)
def create_integration_company(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        company_integration_id = third_party.create_crm_company(instance)
        instance.integration_id = company_integration_id
        instance.save()
```

When I ran our tests, it created thousands of accounts in this third party's system, so I discovered `mock`.

We have a bunch of tests that create companies and I was wondering if I have to add this to every one of them? `@mock.patch("apps.accounts.utils.build_request", return_value="123")`

My question is: at which level should I mock the response and just return `123` for the new integration id? Can I do it at the model level? Or do I have to do this for every test case we have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocking will work but the better option would be to disconnect the signals for the unit tests. Please see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/#disconnecting-signals on how to disconnect signal. You can create a test-only mixin which you can include in your test suite. Ideally, you can do this in mixin's init or setUpClass. Say the mixin is SignalDisconnector, which you will use as:

```
class TestSuite(TestCase, SignalDisconnector)
```

This will only test the behavior which you are intending in the test suite without experiencing any side effects.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thank you! Can the dispatch_uid be hard coded in the statement to connect the receiver to the signal ie `@receiver(post_save, sender=Company, dispatch_uid='my_unique_uid')`, or does that value have to be assigned dynamically? There are just multiple post_save signals being sent and I just want to ignore mine, so I wanted to know if I could disconnect my signal using that dispatch_uid @Syed Muhammad Dawoud Sheraz Al

Comment: It is possible to hardcode dispatch_uid. The uid should be unique across various receivers as it helps in identifying the correct receiver when connecting/disconnecting the signal handlers. 

Ref:
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/#listening-to-signals
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/#disconnecting-signals

Comment: Ok, but that makes it easy to disconnect it because I can just call `Signal.disconnect(post_save, dispatch_uid="my_unique_uid")` and then that means that that particular signal will be disconnected. And I can just add it to my setUp function in my test files that need it, correct?

Comment: Yes. And this will be true only for your testing environment/CI. One thing I would suggest is that if you disconnect the signal in setUp, connect it back in tearDown. I can't find an exact reference but, sometimes such disconnect in one test suite can affect the execution of other test suites.